How to make compiler throw error when type can not be `undefined`?
I have type ILoadedValue<TValue>, which should be used as a wrapper for types, which can be undefined, but prevent usages when TValue can not be undefined (because in such cases it is more efficient to not wrap type, but to use undefined to indicate that type is still being loaded)
Currently I use TValue extends undefined
/**
 * {@link ILoadedValue} is needed to provide atomically information
 * about value and loaded status for values which can be `undefined`,
 * it should be used like `ILoadedValue<TValue> | undefined`
 *
 * Notice that we should avoid usages when `TValue` can not be `undefined`
 * (because in such cases it is more efficient to not wrap type,
 * but to use `undefined` to indicate that type is still being loaded)
 */
export interface ILoadedValue<TValue extends undefined> {
  value: TValue;
}

But if we use this type in other type, like
export class SomeClass<TValue> {
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue | undefined> | undefined;
}

we get error

TS2344: Type TValue | undefined does not satisfy the constraint undefined
Type TValue is not assignable to type undefined
SomeClass.ts(40, 3): This type parameter might need an extends undefined constraint.


Can you propose a better approach, so that these cases behaved as expected?
export class SomeClass<TValue> {
  // Should be ok
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue | undefined> | undefined;
}

export class SomeClass2<TValue> {
  // Compiler should throw, because `TValue` is not guaranteed to contain `undefined`
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue> | undefined;
}


Please [edit] to provide adequate debugging details and a [mre].  Saying "it misbehaves in some cases" unfortunately does not suffice. You should show us what "cases" you're talking about.  TValue extends undefined should work, but it there's no point in having it generic at all; it should just be value: undefined. But without a [mre] I couldn't even begin to hope to answer this.

Oh, you want a lower bound constraint, like TValue super undefined, but TS doesn't directly support those. You can simulate it with a conditional type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining (or find a suitable duplicate target). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks, checking it now (need to rebuild some stuff)

@jcalz Thanks! Your answer is exactly what I needed. Can you add this answer, or should I do it?

I will do it when I get a chance.

You don't want to constrain TValue to undefined, since that forces TValue to be some subtype of undefined. Which pretty much is only undefined or never.  Instead, you want the opposite: where TValue is a supertype of undefined. Instead of TValue extends undefined, you want to say undefined extends TValue, or TValue super undefined.  That is, undefined should be a lower bound instead of an upper bound.
TypeScript doesn't directly support lower bound constraints. There's a longstanding open feature request for that at microsoft/TypeScript#14520, but for now it's not part of the language. If you want to see that happen you might consider giving it a , but even if it does eventually get implemented, you need a solution in the meantime.

One way to proceed is to simulate a lower bound constraint by using a conditional type like this:
interface ILoadedValue<TValue extends (undefined extends TValue ? unknown : never)> {
  value: TValue;
}

class SomeClass<TValue> {
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue | undefined> | undefined; // okay
}

class SomeClass2<TValue> {
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue> | undefined; // error
}

That works because when undefined extends TValue is true, the constraint is TValue extends unknown which always passes... but when undefined extends TValue is false, the constraint is TValue extends never which (almost) never passes.
It works, but it's a bit clunky.

Depending on your use case, you might want to just forget about lower bound constraints and use a union to include undefined in the domain of everything that uses TValue.  Instead of interface F<T super X> {⋯T⋯}, you can write interface F {⋯(U | X)⋯}whereTis equivalent toT | X`.  Those are essentially equivalent, they just express things in terms of different type variables.
In your case that looks like:
interface ILoadedValue<UValue> {
  value: UValue | undefined;
}

class SomeClass<TValue> {
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue | undefined> | undefined; // okay
}

class SomeClass2<TValue> {
  loadedValue: ILoadedValue<TValue> | undefined; // okay 
  // because it's the same as SomeClass<TValue>
}

Now you can always write ILoadedValue<TValue> and it will end up including undefined.  Maybe that doesn't work for you, but it's much simpler.
Playground link to code
